# Ionic2 adicionar elemento na view

Tags: typescript, ionic2

Preciso criar um evento click que ao ser pressionado crie um input na view.
Como posso fazer isso ?
Obrigado
Ps: uso ionic2 typescript

HTML

```html
<ion-navbar *navbar>
  <ion-title>
    POSimplex
  </ion-title>
</ion-navbar>

<ion-content class="home" padding>
  <button ion-button full>Login</button>
  <p>
    <button ion-button full>Criar conta</button>
  </p>
  <p>{{ sl }}</p>
</ion-content>
```

Typescript

```html
import {Component} from "@angular/core";
import {NavController} from 'ionic-angular';

@Component({
  templateUrl: 'build/pages/home/home.html'
})
export class HomePage {
  sl: string
  constructor(private navController: NavController) {this.sl = '<button ion-button full>Criar conta</button>'}
}
```

Comment: O que você já fez? Poste o código para melhor lhe ajudarmos.

Comment: Na realidade tentei fazer um teste sem o click, só para testar ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Coloque o evento de click:

```
<button ion-button full (click)="inserirCampo()">Adicionar campo</button>
```

Como você já deve saber, o Ionic usa o AngularJS, a inserção "infinita" de elementos no DOM (que eu costumo fazer), consiste em ter uma div contendo um repeater (`ngFor`) trabalhando sobre uma variável do escopo.

```
<div *ngFor="let item of inputs">
    <input type="text">
</div>
```

Com isso, na sua função `inserirCampo` você vai inserir um novo item na sua variável do escopo:

```
this.inputs.push(novoItem);
```

Tendo o *two way data binding* do Angular, assim que você inserir na variável do escopo, o input será exibido na página.

**Typescript:**

```
export class MinhaPagina {
  inputs: Array<{title: string, type: string, value: string}>;

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams) {

      this.inputs = [
          { title: "teste", type: "text", value: "valor" },
          { title: "teste2", type: "text", value: "valor2" }
      ];
  }

  adicionarCampo() {
      this.inputs.push({ title: "teste", type: "text", value: "valor" });
  }
}
```

**.html**

```
<ion-content>
    <ion-list>
        <ion-item *ngFor="let item of inputs">
            <ion-label fixed>{{item.title}}</ion-label>
            <ion-input type="{{item.type}}" value="{{item.value}}"></ion-input>
        </ion-item>
    </ion-list>
    <button ion-button class="button" (click)="adicionarCampo()">Adicionar campo</button>
</ion-content>
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

> Obs. Seu código não funcionava porque você usou *ngfor ao invés de *ngFor

Comment: sem sucesso ...

Comment: @AugustoFurlan O que você não conseguiu fazer?

Comment: coloquei como vc falou, mas não deu certo ...

Comment: @AugustoFurlan A solução que eu propus funciona. Estou criando um fiddle pra te mostrar e já posto aqui

Comment: ok muito obg...

Comment: Renan você está usando typescript? Pois achei estranho ...

Comment: @AugustoFurlan como a ideia de mostrar o fiddle não te ajudou muito, criei a mesma aplicação aqui, só tinha um pequeno erro no seu código que era *ngfor ao invés de *ngFor. Veja se consegue agora

Comment: Araujo, você tem o projeto no wetransfer ou github ? pois tentei fazer e não deu certo ...

Comment: @AugustoFurlan Criei um utilizando blank https://github.com/renanaraujo/infiniteFields

Comment: deu certo ... muito obrigado